# Node js - How to passing parameter with require

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

In controller I did a require to `config/db` but I need to send a parameter with database name because I can have several databases.

So in controller I do this:

```
    "use strict";
var connection = require('../config/db', function(db)
{
  var db = "Emp1";
});
var connection = require('../config/db');
var mssql = require('mssql');
var request = new mssql.Request(connection);
var parser = require('json-parser');
var squel = require("squel");

class RecpetionController
{
  init(app)
  {
    app.get("/", (req, res) => this.index.call(this, req, res));
  }

  index(req, res)
  {
    console.log('Index reception')
  }

}
module.exports = RecpetionController;
```

In `config/db` I have this:

```
    var mssql = require("mssql");

console.log('DATABASE');

 if(db == 'Emp1')
 {
   var config =
   {
     user: "user",
     password: "pass",
     server: "ip",
     database: "Emp1"
   }
 }
 else if(db == 'Emp2')
 {
   var config =
   {
     user: "user",
     password: "pass",
     server: "ip",
     database: "Emp2"
   }
 }

 var connection = new mssql.Connection(config);

 connection.connect(function(err)
 {
     console.log(err);
 });

 module.exports = connection;
```

So I'm passing the right way the value from controllers?

How can I receive the value in `config/db` ?

If in `config/db` I  `console.log(arguments)` it don't show me any field with db value...

How can i solve this.

It's better way to use `node-cache` to obtain the db name in `config/db`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. So instead, you make `config/db` return a factory for connections, not a connection. The old-style Node callback way would look something like this *(this is **conceptual**, not meant to be perfect)*:

```
var mssql = require("mssql");

module.exports = function getConnection(db, callback) {
    if (db == 'Emp1') {
        var config = {
            user: "user",
            password: "pass",
            server: "ip",
            database: "Emp1"
        }
    }
    else if (db == 'Emp2') {
        var config = {
            user: "user",
            password: "pass",
            server: "ip",
            database: "Emp2"
        }
    }

    var connection = new mssql.Connection(config);

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};
```

...then use it like this:

```
var connection = require('../config/db')('Emp1', function(err, connection) {
    // Use `err` and `connection` here
});
```

Or you might separate creating the connection from the `connect` call and have the module using the connection do the `connect`. Lots of ways to approach it.

---

A more modern API would use Promises (for their own sake, and to enable use of `async`/`await`):

```
var mssql = require("mssql");

module.exports = function getConnection(db, callback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (db == 'Emp1') {
            var config = {
                user: "user",
                password: "pass",
                server: "ip",
                database: "Emp1"
            }
        }
        else if (db == 'Emp2') {
            var config = {
                user: "user",
                password: "pass",
                server: "ip",
                database: "Emp2"
            }
        }

        var connection = new mssql.Connection(config);
        connection.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(connection);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

then

```
require('../config/db')('Emp1')
    .then(function(connection) {
        // Use `connection` here
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // Use `err` here
    });
```

---

In the above I've stayed with ES5 syntax (Promises can be supplied by a module if you're using a really old version of Node), as your code currently seems to avoid using ES2015+ features.

---

Finally: I'd suggest changing your config selection to use an object or `Map`:

```
var configs = {
    Emp1: {
        user: "user",
        password: "pass",
        server: "ip",
        database: "Emp1"
    },
    Emp2: {
        user: "user",
        password: "pass",
        server: "ip",
        database: "Emp2"
    }
};
```

then

```
var config = configs[db];
```

Perhaps even loading them from a file...

Comment: Thank you a lot @T.J.Crowder, works!
Now what is the better way to store database name? In cache?
In login the user has to select database and I'm thinking in login controller set the database name in cache. What do you think about that? Thank you

Comment: @user3242861: I don't know what you mean by "cache" in this instance. Where you store that selection will depend on the overall structure of your app.